# ERROR: HDLCompiler:806 ... Syntax error near "end"

Tags: verilog, fpga, i2c

I'm trying to make an I2C protocol on Verilog, and I was typing what this guy was typing (a [video on YouTube that explains how to make a I2C BUS protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skkyudHHSWY))

```
module step1(
input wire clk,
input wire reset,
output reg i2c_sda,
output reg i2c_scl
);

//goal is to write to device addres 0x50, 0xaa

localparam STATE_IDLE = 0;
localparam STATE_START = 1;
localparam STATE_ADDR = 2;
localparam STATE_RW = 3;
localparam STATE_WACK = 4;
localparam STATE_DATA = 5;
localparam STATE_STOP = 6;
localparam STATE_WACK2 = 7;
reg [7:0] state;
reg [6:0] addr;
reg [7:0] data; 
reg [7:0] count;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset == 1) begin
        state <= 0;
        i2c_sda <= 1;
        i2c_scl <= 1;
        addr <= 7'h50;
        count <= 8'd0;
        data <= 8'haa;
    end
    else begin
        case(state)

            STATE_IDLE: begin //idle
                i2c_sda <= 1;
                state <= STATE_START;
            end // end state idle

            STATE_START: begin //start  
                i2c_sda <= 1;
                state <= STATE_ADDR;
                count <= 6;
            end // end of state start

            STATE_ADDR: begin // fisrt addres bit or the most significant adress bit
                i2c_sda <= addr[count];
                if (count == 0) state <= STATE_RW;
                else count <= count - 1;
            end // end of state ADDR

            STATE_RW: begin // Read or Write opperation
                i2c_sda <= 1;
                state <= STATE_WACK;
            end // end state RW

            STATE_WACK: begin
                state <= STATE_DATA;
                count <= 7;
            end // end of state WACK

            STATE_DATA: begin
                i2c_sda <= data[count];
                if (count == 0) state <= STATE_WACK2;
                else count <= count-1;
            end // end of state DATA

            STATE_WACK2: begin
                state <= STATE_STOP;
            end // end state WACK2

            STATE_STOP: begin
                i2c_sda <= 1;
                state <= STATE_IDLE;
            end // end of state STOP

        end// end of case
    end // end of the else
  end // end of if
endmodule
```

But, when I try to compile, the following error pops out. I really don't understand why, because all end are correct (at least for me):

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/home/yunta23/Documentos/Digital1/VideosYou/primero/step1/step1.v" Line 97: Syntax error near "end".
```

Comment: Your error states that it is on Line 97. There are only 80 lines in the code you posted. This makes it more difficult for us to determine where the compiler believes the error is. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Producing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may have resulted in you to finding the error on your own.

Answer (score 3):

A `case` statement requires the `endcase` keyword, not an `end` keyword.  Change:

```
    end// end of case
```

to:

```
    endcase
```